# Haskell where statement returns parse error on input ‘=’

Tags: haskell

This function I made returns a `parse error on input ‘=’`

```
checkappend :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Maybe [a]
checkappend ml1 ml2 test =
    if all test l1
    then (Just (l1 ++ l2))
    else Nothing
    where l1 = fromJust(ml1)
        l2 = fromJust(ml2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where` needs to be indented less than the function body, any consistently:

```
checkappend ml1 ml2 test =
    if all test l1
     then Just (l1 ++ l2)
     else Nothing
  where l1 = fromJust ml1
        l2 = fromJust ml2
```

BTW, using partial functions like `head` or `fromJust` is bad style. Better use pattern matching on `Maybe` arguments! Also, `if` `then` `else` is somewhat unpopular in Haskell – guards tend to look nicer:

```
checkappend (Just l1) (Just l2) test
  | all test l1  = Just $ l1 ++ l2
  | otherwise    = Nothing
```

Of course, the pattern match is still incomplete... what to do if one of the arguments is `Nothing`? I reckon you want to result to be `Nothing` then, too; that's possible with a catch-all pattern:

```
checkappend (Just l1) (Just l2) test
  | all test l1   = Just $ l1 ++ l2
checkappend _ _ _ = Nothing
```

Note that this already includes the `| otherwise` guard: if no guard for a given pattern clause matches, Haskell just continues with the next clause.

Comment: Thanks, what does this line do `checkappend _ _ _ = Nothing` and how is different then `otherwise = Nothing`

Comment: @DanielKobe, the `otherwise = Nothing` doesn't handle the case where one or both of the arguments is `Nothing`. `_` is a wildcard pattern that matches anything and ignores it. If the `all test l1` guard fails, the matcher will try the next line, `checkappend _ _ _`, which will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

A really slick way to write it:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

checkAppend m1 m2 test =
  do
    l1 <- m1
    l2 <- m2
    guard $ all test l1
    return $ l1 ++ l2
```

This uses the fact that `Maybe` is a monad with a notion of failure. If either of the arguments is nothing, it fails to extract `l1` or `l2` and gives `Nothing`. If the `guard` argument is false, it gives `Nothing`. Finally, if all goes well, it gives `Just (l1 ++ l2)`.

For fun, try writing the function I just gave and applying it to two lists of lists, instead of two maybe lists. What does it do? Can you figure out why?